# Need some help about "swap" function in c++

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ programming. I am trying to compile another person's program, and the software reported a bug that I don't know how to solve (the software I use is Visual Studio 2019).

The line of code with bug is:

```
swap(allBeamPoints, unordered_map<int, vector<LidarPoint>>());
```

The definition for variable `allBeamPoints` is:

```
unordered_map<int, vector<LidarPoint>>allBeamPoints
```

The error information is:

```
Error   C2665   'std::swap': none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types
```

and

```
Error (active)  E0304   no instance of overloaded function "swap" matches the argument list
```

However, if I type the following codes, no bug will be reported:

```
unordered_map<int, vector<LidarPoint>> allBeamPoints_new;

swap(allBeamPoints, allBeamPoints_new);
```

Does anyone know what the problem is? Did I fail to link some of the required libraries? How should I check those libraries?

Comment: `std::swap` expect two non-temporary objects. `unordered_map<int, vector>()` is a temporary object, so it cannot be swapped with. I'm not even sure why you are using `swap` here, you seem to want to `clear` the map instead?

Comment: `unordered_map` has its own [`swap()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/swap) method, so you could do `unordered_map<int, vector<LidarPoint>>().swap(allBeamPoints);` But UnholySheep is right, you should use [`clear()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/clear) instead: `allBeamPoints.clear();`

Comment: Yeah the "allBeamPoints.clear();" works, thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 4):

The older MSVC compilers allowed the binding of an anonymous temporary to a non-`const` reference function parameter. That's not standard C++.

So

```
swap(allBeamPoints, unordered_map<int, vector<LidarPoint>>());
```

which had the effect of clearing `allBeamPoints` was reasonably idiomatic in code that only targeted Microsoft platforms.

It's wrong and not portable as you now observe. Use

```
allBeamPoints.clear();
```

instead to clear the map. Your second snippet compiles since `allBeamPoints_new` is not an anonymous temporary.

Comment: Ok I understand now, thank you so much! :)